# Is it possible to use a `dask` array as input for `pyspark`?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, dask

Is it possible to use a `dask` array as input for `pyspark`?

I have a `dask` array that I like to feed to `pyspark.mllib.clustering.StreamingKMeans`.

Answer (score 1):

There was once a proof-of-concept for using Dask as a preprocessing layer for handing off work to Spark, where the dask and spark workers were co-located. I don't believe the effort was ever pushed far or used in any kind of production, so the short answer is "no", there's no way to directly pass a dask array to spark. As things stand, you would need to compute the whole thing the client, or write to a storage system that both frameworks can see